# How to enable labels in vaadin VerticalLayout for copy-paste

Tags: label, vaadin, copy-paste

I am using VerticalLayout and nested Labels for simple printing messages on the page.
Displayed rows cannot be extracted by copy-paste. I found out, only caption can be taken into clipboard from labels, but the content cannot.

```
public final VerticalLayout debugLayout = new VerticalLayout();
.
.
.
debugLayout.addLayoutClickListener(new LayoutClickListener(){

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void layoutClick(final LayoutClickEvent event) {
        debugLayout.addComponent(new Label("click"));
    }
});

Label l=new Label("The first text to be displayed, f.e. multiline SQL-command");
l.setContentMode(ContentMode.PREFORMATTED);
l.setWidth("100%");
debugLayout.addComponent(l);
.
.
public void resetDebug() {
    debugLayout.removeAllComponents();
    debugLayout.setWidth("100%");
    debugLayout.addComponent(new Button("Reset", new Button.ClickListener(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            resetDebug();
        }
    }));
}
```

Now I cannot take the SQL command into clipboard.

Why? And how to enable the copy-paste functionality for the label value?

Click event in the VerticalLayout works fine, new lines "click" are added.

Reset button works too.

Thanks for help.

Comment: you you please provide more infos about this issue (e.g. code example, what browser/OS used)?  text from labels in layout can be perfectly marked and copied.  e.g. http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-presentation/label

Comment: Now I found out, the problem is elsewhere. The selection doesn't start from click. I cannot place pointer between two characters. If there is another object on the page I can place focus in, then I am able to select all texts by Ctrl-A, including all labels. But not inside the VerticalLayout. The same in MSIE 11 and FF 31

Comment: Is all of this in a panel (or similar) and is it capturing mouse events?

Comment: Yes, it is nested in several containers. I never paid attention to their capturing events. If there is a table or input components, then all is enabled.

Comment: New example has been added. Click event on the layout or on a button is captured fine.

Comment: Given that this is an artificial example what are your real intents when clicking in the layout?  In the end it prevents marking the text.  The fastest way to prevent this problem would be to add the `click`-Label also as a button and not using the `LayoutClickListener`.

Comment: The VerticalLayout is placed in a debug panel/window by setContent method. In fact I cannot need to click here, but another components display SQL commands here. I need to take them and move using clipboard to SQL management tool for subsequent debugging. I tried it first time and met this problem. Its demo content I created for You to discover if click event works. By clicking, new rows are added and the button clears them. It is intended as debug window acessible from another modules, that can write here what they wish. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why, but displaying in separate window works fine:

```
// sessionContext is my object that contains the content
Window w1=new Window("Debug window", sessionContext.debugLayout);
w1.setWidth("600px");
w1.setHeight("400px");
w1.center();
UI.getCurrent().addWindow(w1);
```

The question why it doesn't work in my working panel remains unanswered.
If anybody wants to continue investigating, there is an additional information:

My working panel is placed in main UI, which consists of:

- page header (user account identification properties)
- menu bar
- working panel - rest of the page, maybe auto-sizing would be the problem. All menu items replace its caption and content.

Thank you all who were dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Now I know, what can help:

Easily remove additional themes support from your scss files:

```
@import "../base/base.scss";
@import "../reindeer/reindeer.scss";

/*
@import "../runo/runo.scss";
@import "../liferay/liferay.scss";
@import "../chameleon/chameleon.scss";
@import "../valo/_valo.scss";
*/
```

"base" and "reindeer" are OK. Another make the problem. After excluding by comment i compiled themes and now the clipboard copy-paste works.

Welcome, if somebody has any explanation.